# Getting closest point on grid to point

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry

I have a one dimensional gird. its spacing is a floating point. I have a point with floating point coordinate as well. I need to find its distance to the closest grid point.
For example:

```
            0.12
             |
             *
 |---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
 0        0.1       0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5
```

The result would be `-0.02` since the closest point is behind it.
However if it was

```
                -0.66
                  |
                  *
 |---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
-1       -0.8      -0.6      -0.4      -0.2        0
```

The result will be `0.06`. As you can see its in floating point and can be negative.
I tried the following:

```
float spacing = ...;
float point = ...;

while(point >= spacing) point -= spacing;
while(point < 0) point += spacing;

if(std::abs(point - spacing) < point) point -= spacing;
```

It works, but I'm sure there is a way without loops

Comment: In his examples it is linear.

Comment: @MooingDuck: its linear, just not constant (its parameter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us first compute the nearest points on the left and right as follows:

```
leftBorder = spacing * floor(point/spacing);
rightBorder = leftBorder + spacing;
```

Then the distance is straightforward:

```
if ((point - leftBorder) < (rightBorder - point))
    distance = leftBorder - point;
else
    distance = rightBorder - point;
```

Note that, we could find the nearest points alternatively by ceiling:

```
rightBorder = spacing * ceil(point/spacing);
leftBorder = rightBorder - spacing;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I modified the variables to make it self-expressive. Should I add more explanation?

Comment: An explanation in natural language would only make your answer better so go for it!

Comment: I added some sentences in the natural language :)

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<float> spacing = ...;
float point = ...;
float result;
```

Since you say the spacing isn't (linear), I would cache the sums:

```
std::vector<float> sums(1, 0.0);
float sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<spacing.size(); ++i)
    sums.push_back(sum+=spacing[i]);
//This only needs doing once.
//sums needs to be in increasing order.
```

Then do a binary search to find the point to the left:

```
std::vector<float>::iterator iter;
iter = std::lower_bound(sums.begin(), sums.end(), point);
```

Then find the result from there:

```
if (iter+1 == sums.end())
    return point-*iter;
else {
    float midpoint = (*iter + *(iter+1))/2;
    if (point < midpoint)
        result = point - *iter;
    else
        result = *(iter+1) - point;
}
```

[EDIT] Don't I feel silly.  You said the spacing wasn't constant.  I interpreted that as not-linear.  But then your sample code *is* linear, just not a compile-time constant.  My bad.  I'll leave this answer as a more general solution, though your (linear) question is solvable much faster.

Comment: The spacing is constant inside invocation, its not constant between invocations...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my first blush attempt, note that this is not tested at all.

```
float remainder = fmod(point, spacing); // This is the fractional difference of the spaces
int num_spaces = point/spacing;  // This is the number of "spaces" down you are, rounded down


// If our fractional part is greater than half of the space length, increase the number of spaces.
// Not sure what you want to do when the point is equidistant to both grid points
if(remainder > .5 * spacing) 
{
  ++num_spaces;
}

float closest_value = num_spaces*spacing;
float distance = closest_value - point;
```

Comment: In his comment to your answer he says it is constant within invocations.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No he states that it isn't constant.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I didn't state its not linear, I just state its not 0.1 always. (its a parameter)

Comment: @Dani: I misinterpreted the comment.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should just round the number using this:

```
float spacing = ...;
float point = ...;
(point > 0.0) ? floor(point + spacing/2) : ceil(point - spacing/2);
```

Comment: @Dani: I clarified how it can be done with non-constant spacing.

Comment: floor and ceiling round to the nearest integer, not the nearest step value.

Answer (score 0):

Much, much more generally, for arbitrary spacing, dimensions, and measures of distance (metric), the structure you're looking for would be a Voronoi Diagram.